# Автоматическая смена категории записей Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Доброе время суток. Возникла такая необходимость на Wordpress:
Есть две категории записей:

1. Новый записи
2. Старые записи

Задача стоит следующая: Как перенести автоматически записи (без вмешательства администратора сайта), которым к примеру 1 неделя, с категории - "Новые записи" в "Старые записи" ?

Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Какие-то идеи есть  в этой [статье](https://wp-kama.ru/id_53/peremeschaem-kuchu-statey-v-druguyu-kategoriyu.html) но останется ещё привязать к датам публикации.

Comment: Как различаются записи указанных категорий на уровне хранения (в таблицах БД)? В принципе просто из планировщика (встроенного в СУБД, при отсутствии - внешнего) периодически выполняется обновление записей с присвоением статуса старых тем записям, которые соответствуют критерию возраста и ещё не помечены как старые.

Comment: @Quazimorda *Какие-то идеи есть в этой статье* А какой великий смысл гонять записи на клиента и обратно?

Comment: @Akina Никакого. Лучше в самом деле реализовать как скрипт по расписанию в БД. Однако, ссылка, что я привёл - была чуть ли не первой, что выдал поиск на данный вопрос.

Comment: @klifort ссылка от  Quazimord + WP-Cron https://misha.blog/wordpress/wp_cron.html